# RESTful API design - /users/:userId/resourceType vs. /resourceType/?user=:userId

Tags: api, restful-url

I'm spinning my tires a bit and I'm curious to know what others have decided on given the same scenario.

To get a list of `resourceType` for user identified by `:userId` from a RESTful API, what URI pattern makes the most sense, if I have resources that would be addressed as:

> /users/:userId/resourceType // Return list of resourceType for :userId

versus:

> /resourceType/?userId=:userID // Query a list of the resourceType

I keep thinking "do both" - but it feels impractical considering how many permutations are possible with complex resource models.

Is it just 'pick one and move on' scenario or is there one that's pragmatically better than the other and I'm just not seeing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely don't do both! You're just making support work for yourself. It's best if an API only provides one way to do a thing.

Either will work. It depends on how tightly resource types are coupled to users. If there's a tight coupling, then (1) is fine. If you're not sure, or if they are only loosely coupled, then (2) is preferable.